# 413 Request Entity Too Large (Wordpress Laravel Forge)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-forge

It's my first time to use WordPress using [laravel forge](https://forge.laravel.com/). I already installed WordPress but the thing is when I upload a new theme .zip file, I notice that the upload is running but after that it says:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

Tried also changing these lines below inside site *FPM Configuration*

```
memory_limit = 256M
pload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 60M
```

I think I need to set the filesize capacity on nginx but I don't know where it's lcoated . Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to your server configuration > PHP options at Forge, there you will find option to increase max file upload size.

Hope this helps!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The issue is related to the nginx server's buffer memory. Try increasing the following parameter:

```
http {
  client_max_body_size 20M;         
}
```

You can do this in the server's nginx file in forge panel.

Comment: Am just using raw Nginx configurations and this really helped. Thanks!